# Filtering repeater items by multiple selection-Tags in Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I am building a wix website with a data collection (projects) with multiple selection-tag fields (departmentTags, orgnisationTags, sectionTags, statusTags). I have created a repeater on my website to display the data collection, and want to filter the items displayed based on multiple selection-tag filters.

For now I have filtered the list only based on a single set of selection tags (departmentTags). So when a departmentTag is selected the list of projects which belong to that department are filtered

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const collectionName = 'projects';

$w.onReady(function () { 

    setRepeatedItemsInRepeater()
    loadDataToRepeater()

    $w('#departmentTags').onChange((event) => {
        const selectedTags = $w('#departmentTags').value
        loadDataToRepeater(selectedTags)
    })
    
});

function setRepeatedItemsInRepeater() {
    $w('#projectRepeater').onItemReady(($item, itemData) => {

        $item('#projectImage').src = itemData.Image;
        $item('#projectTitle').text = itemData.Title;
        $item('#projectSummary').text = itemData.Summary;

    })
}

function loadDataToRepeater(selectedCategories = []) {

    let dataQuery = wixData.query(collectionName)

    if (selectedCategories.length > 0) {
        dataQuery = dataQuery.hasAll('department', selectedCategories)
    }
    
    dataQuery
        .find()
        .then(results => {
            const itemsReadyForRepeater = results.items
            $w('#projectRepeater').data = itemsReadyForRepeater;
        })
}
```

I now also want to include the rest of the selection-tags in filtering the projects. For example I want a user to be able to select departments, organisations and statuses, and the listed projects on the repeater to be filtered by all three categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would need to set the `onChange` of all the tag elements to some function like this:

```
function tagChange() {
  const selectedDepts = $w('#departmentTags').value;
  const selectedOrgs = $w('#organizationTags').value;
  const selectedStatuses = $w('#statusTags').value;

  loadDataToRepeater(selectedDepts, selectedOrgs, selectedStatuses);
}
```

Then, modify the `loadDataToRepeater` function to look something like this:

```
function loadDataToRepeater(selectedDepts, selectedOrgs, selectedStatuses) {

    wixData.query(collectionName)
      .hasAll('department', selectedDepts)
      .hasAll('organization', selectedOrgs)
      .hasAll('status', selectedStatuses)
      .find()
      .then(results => {
        $w('#projectRepeater').data = results.items;
      });
}
```